# ListView in vsReport mode colouring of Items and rows

Tags: delphi, listview, colors, row, brush

I want to color one row in gray and the other in white.
I have the following code but there is white space of vertical lines of columns in Windows 7.
How do I color all rows?

```
procedure TForm2.Update_ListBoxCustomDrawItem(Sender: TCustomListView;
  Item: TListItem; State: TCustomDrawState; var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
begin
 if Item.Index mod 2=0
 then
  begin
   Sender.Canvas.Font.Color:=clBlack;
   Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color:=$F6F6F6;
  end
 else
  begin
   Sender.Canvas.Font.Color:=clBlack;
   Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color:=clWhite;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I've merged your two accounts together. [Please read this Faq entry about cookie-based accounts.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account/1228)

Answer (score 9):

Set `OwnerDraw` to `true` and add

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1DrawItem(Sender: TCustomListView; Item: TListItem;
  Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
var
  i: Integer;
  x1, x2: integer;
  r: TRect;
  S: string;
const
  DT_ALIGN: array[TAlignment] of integer = (DT_LEFT, DT_RIGHT, DT_CENTER);
begin
  if Odd(Item.Index) then
  begin
    Sender.Canvas.Font.Color := clBlack;
    Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := $F6F6F6;
  end
  else
  begin
    Sender.Canvas.Font.Color := clBlack;
    Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite;
  end;
  Sender.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
  Sender.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
  x1 := 0;
  x2 := 0;
  r := Rect;
  Sender.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
  for i := 0 to ListView1.Columns.Count - 1 do
  begin
    inc(x2, ListView1.Columns[i].Width);
    r.Left := x1;
    r.Right := x2;
    if i = 0 then
      S := Item.Caption
    else
      S := Item.SubItems[i - 1];
    DrawText(Sender.Canvas.Handle,
      S,
      length(S),
      r,
      DT_SINGLELINE or DT_ALIGN[ListView1.Columns[i].Alignment] or
        DT_VCENTER or DT_END_ELLIPSIS);
    x1 := x2;
  end;
end;
```

[image: Screenshot]

In the above example, the first column is left-aligned and the two other are centered.

If you only have one column, that is, no subitems:

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1DrawItem(Sender: TCustomListView; Item: TListItem;
  Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
var
  r: TRect;
  S: string;
const
  DT_ALIGN: array[TAlignment] of integer = (DT_LEFT, DT_RIGHT, DT_CENTER);
begin
  if odd(Item.Index) then
  begin
    Sender.Canvas.Font.Color:=clBlack;
    Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color:=$F6F6F6;
  end
  else
  begin
    Sender.Canvas.Font.Color:=clBlack;
    Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color:=clWhite;
  end;
  Sender.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
  Sender.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
  r := Rect;
  Sender.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
  S := Item.Caption;
  DrawText(Sender.Canvas.Handle,
    S,
    length(S),
    r,
    DT_SINGLELINE or DT_ALIGN[ListView1.Columns[0].Alignment] or DT_VCENTER or DT_END_ELLIPSIS);
end;
```

Comment: There is slightly more to it (and exactly what this is depends on your particular situation), but this should get you started, at least.

Comment: if I have not a text in SubItem what to do? And how to draw an image for Item? Thanks.

Comment: If you don't have any subitems, you only have one column. Then it is even easier. You simply remove a few lines of the code above.

Comment: Please help me to do it if I have subitems that can be not filled with text + Items have icons. Thanks!

Comment: I thought it worthy of comment - the line: 'S := Item.SubItems[i];' ought to be 'S := Item.SubItems[i-1];' Otherwise you get list index errors.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Getting 'list index out of bounds(1)' every time the list getting refreshed, also bitmaps does not show in subitem cells (i have an imagelist bounded to the listviews's smallimages property).

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Yes there is an indexing problem. 
Change the 'S := Item.SubItems[i]' row to 'S := Item.SubItems[i-1];' Of course it does not help with the problem that my image does not get showed.