# Delphi: Paint Rows of ListView

Tags: delphi, listview, colors, row, paint

I have a ListView (vsReport): the last SubItem has a text "wait". Then I will change it to "ok" or "error". How to paint a whole row (if to use  Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color in CustomDrawItem it will be gaps between columns in Windows 7) with this SubItem in green (ok) and red (error)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1CustomDrawItem(Sender: TCustomListView;
  Item: TListItem; State: TCustomDrawState; var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
begin
  if Item.Index = Sender.Items.Count - 1 then
  begin
    Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := clSkyBlue;
    Sender.Canvas.FillRect(Item.DisplayRect(drBounds));
  end;
end;
```

but I advice against it, because it is buggy (and I don't know how to fix it).

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What exactly is buggy about this method, please?

Comment: Try to move a mouse over and you will see :)

Comment: I have many applications and all of them paint normally without gaps. I never had a program that had gaps in a ListView.

Comment: Ok, how to paint rows in my case without FillRect (I am asking how to paint in my case. Technically I know how-Canvas.Brush.Color). It is better than nothing.

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand, if to use your code from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294985/listview-in-vsreport-mode-colouring-of-items-and-rows  How to draw a Small Image in the first column (Item)?? Thanks.

Comment: @maxfax: Load the image and draw it.

Comment: @ Andreas Rejbrand, I cannot find an answer how to draw a Small Image, I did not do it bedore.

Comment: @maxfax: If you ask a *new* question that asks how to extend [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294985/listview-in-vsreport-mode-colouring-of-items-and-rows) to draw small icons, then I can post a simple example for you.

Comment: done, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612797/delphi-how-to-draw-small-icons-in-list-view-on-customdrawitem