# Delphi: how to draw small icons in List View on CustomDrawItem

Tags: delphi, listview, graphics, draw

how to extend this code: [ListView in vsReport mode colouring of Items and rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294985/listview-in-vsreport-mode-colouring-of-items-and-rows) to draw small icons?

and why do I have the error 'List index out of bounds (2)' if I have 3 columns?

Thanks!

Comment: About the bug in the old code, if you have three items, the first one is stored in `Caption` and the remaining two are found in `Subitems[0]` and `Subitems[1]`, respectively.

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand, thank than thank you!!!!!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many ways to draw the icons, depending on where they come frome (a file, a resource, a system icon, etc.) and depending on if there should be a single icon for all items or if every item has its own icon. Anyhow, the general idea should be clear from this extended version of the code in the previous question (and I have also fixed the out-of-bounds bug...):

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  ...
  private
    { Private declarations }
    bm: TBitmap;
  ...
  end;

...

implementation

...

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  bm := TBitmap.Create;
  bm.LoadFromFile('C:\Users\Andreas Rejbrand\Desktop\img.bmp');
end;

procedure TForm1.ListView1DrawItem(Sender: TCustomListView; Item: TListItem;
  Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
var
  i: Integer;
  x1, x2: integer;
  r: TRect;
  S: string;
const
  DT_ALIGN: array[TAlignment] of integer = (DT_LEFT, DT_RIGHT, DT_CENTER);
begin
  if Odd(Item.Index) then
  begin
    Sender.Canvas.Font.Color := clBlack;
    Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := $F6F6F6;
  end
  else
  begin
    Sender.Canvas.Font.Color := clBlack;
    Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite;
  end;
  Sender.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
  Sender.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
  x1 := 0;
  x2 := 0;
  r := Rect;
  Sender.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
  Sender.Canvas.Draw(3, r.Top + (r.Bottom - r.Top - bm.Height) div 2, bm);
  for i := 0 to ListView1.Columns.Count - 1 do
  begin
    inc(x2, ListView1.Columns[i].Width);
    r.Left := x1;
    r.Right := x2;
    if i = 0 then
    begin
      S := Item.Caption;
      r.Left := bm.Width + 6;
    end
    else
      S := Item.SubItems[i - 1];
    DrawText(Sender.Canvas.Handle,
      S,
      length(S),
      r,
      DT_SINGLELINE or DT_ALIGN[ListView1.Columns[i].Alignment] or
        DT_VCENTER or DT_END_ELLIPSIS);
    x1 := x2;
  end;
end;
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I think I should get a prize for that awesome icon I made in pbrush.

Comment: `TImageList.Draw()` would be another common way to draw an image in this code

Comment: @ David Heffernan, can I have an example?

Comment: like this: ImageList3.Draw(listview1.Canvas,x,y,0,true);

Comment: One small question - how to paint a whole row if I do  on DrawItem: "if Item.SubItems[2]='Done'
   then
  begin
    Sender.Canvas.Font.Color := clBlack;
    Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := clGreen;
  end"   ????? Only the SubItem is filled.

Comment: My goal is to change a text of a subitem and to paint a row in according to the new text of the subitem (error=red,done=green).