# Delphi: Canvas.FillRect in List View

Tags: delphi, listview, fill, brush, rect

On change of a text of List View's SubItem I need to brush and fill a whole row:

```
procedure TForm1.ListViewDrawItem(Sender: TCustomListView;
  Item: TListItem; Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
begin
  if Item.SubItems[2]='Done'
   then
  begin
    Sender.Canvas.Font.Color := clBlack;
    Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := clGreen;
    Sender.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
    Sender.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
  end;
end;
```

But Sender.Canvas.**FillRect(Rect)** will fill only a Rect of the SubItem. How to fill a whole row?

The question is asked on a base of [Delphi: how to draw small icons in List View on CustomDrawItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612797/delphi-how-to-draw-small-icons-in-list-view-on-customdrawitem/6612851#6612851)

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, if you have three columns, they are `Caption`, `SubItems[0]`, and `SubItems[1]`, remember? There is no `SubItems[2]`!

Anyhow, this is very easy. You only need a very, very small modification of the old code.

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1DrawItem(Sender: TCustomListView; Item: TListItem;
  Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
var
  i: Integer;
  x1, x2: integer;
  r: TRect;
  S: string;
const
  DT_ALIGN: array[TAlignment] of integer = (DT_LEFT, DT_RIGHT, DT_CENTER);
begin
  if SameText(Item.SubItems[1], 'done') then
  begin
    Sender.Canvas.Font.Color := clBlack;
    Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := clLime;
  end
  else
    if Odd(Item.Index) then
    begin
      Sender.Canvas.Font.Color := clBlack;
      Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := $F6F6F6;
    end
    else
    begin
      Sender.Canvas.Font.Color := clBlack;
      Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite;
    end;
  Sender.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
  Sender.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
  x1 := 0;
  x2 := 0;
  r := Rect;
  Sender.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
  Sender.Canvas.Draw(3, r.Top + (r.Bottom - r.Top - bm.Height) div 2, bm);
  for i := 0 to ListView1.Columns.Count - 1 do
  begin
    inc(x2, ListView1.Columns[i].Width);
    r.Left := x1;
    r.Right := x2;
    if i = 0 then
    begin
      S := Item.Caption;
      r.Left := bm.Width + 6;
    end
    else
      S := Item.SubItems[i - 1];
    DrawText(Sender.Canvas.Handle,
      S,
      length(S),
      r,
      DT_SINGLELINE or DT_ALIGN[ListView1.Columns[i].Alignment] or
        DT_VCENTER or DT_END_ELLIPSIS);
    x1 := x2;
  end;
end;
```

[image: Screenshot]

Notice in particular that I use `clLime` instead of `clGreen`, because `clBlack` text on a `clGreen` background looks horrible! You might consider `clWhite` text on a `clGreen` background, though:

[image: Screenshot]

**Update in response to comments:**

To change the third column of the list view, it doesn't do to just do

```
procedure TForm1.FormClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ListView1.Items[3].SubItems[1] := 'Done';
end;
```

Indeed, Windows doesn't know that the data of one column affects the appearance of the entire row! <del>The simplest fix is to tell Windows to repaint the entire control when you have changed the value</del> Better: just tell Windows to redraw the current row:

```
procedure TForm1.FormClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ListView1.Items[3].SubItems[1] := 'Done';
  ListView1.Items[3].Update;
end;
```

Comment: the code till " x1 := 0;" fills only a subitem, but not a whole row until I move a mouse on the row, and the row will be repainted.

Comment: I change the text of a SubItem in a Run Time (Items.Item[X].SubItems[2]:='Done'), so it is only filled.

Comment: @maxfax: OK, but that is expected. The Windows control doesn't know that you are changing every column (appearance-wise) when you only change one of them (data-wise). You simply need to call `Invalidate` when you have changed the data.

Comment: @maxfax: Thanks. I just updated the answer with a better solution (performance-wise).

Comment: you have really helped me and answered such many times on my questions

Comment: Everything is wonderful. But you know what, one small disappointment - how to draw a selection of items now? :)

Comment: Your green row looks like a selection, so the design is perhaps not optimal. If you want to draw real selections, you need to write additional code for that, because we are owner-drawing the control. This means that we say to Windows, "hey, don't draw anything in the client area, I'll do that". Therefore, Windows draws nothing, not even selections and mouse-hover effects. If you need that, you have to write it yourself. The code above does neither selections nor mouse-hover effects.

Comment: ok, it will be a new question. I have a drag & drop feature to move rows down and up.