# Delphi: draw selections and mouse-hover effects on ListViewDrawItem

Tags: delphi, listview, drawing, hover, selection

I have a code from here: [Delphi: Canvas.FillRect in List View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617058/delphi-canvas-fillrect-in-list-view) to paint rows (I use OwnerDraw).

Therefore I need to draw selections and mouse-hover effects. And to draw a normal column resizing effect...

I have a code to move items up and down:

```
procedure TForm1.ListViewDragDrop(Sender, Source: TObject; X,
  Y: Integer);
var
  DragItem, DropItem, CurrentItem, NextItem: TListItem;
begin
  if Sender = Source then
    with TListView(Sender) do
    begin
      DropItem    := GetItemAt(X, Y);
      CurrentItem := Selected;
      while CurrentItem <> nil do
      begin
        NextItem := GetNextItem(CurrentItem, SdAll, [IsSelected]);
        if DropItem = nil then DragItem := Items.Add
        else
          DragItem := Items.Insert(DropItem.Index);
        DragItem.Assign(CurrentItem);
        CurrentItem.Free;
        CurrentItem := NextItem;
      end;
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ListViewDragOver(Sender, Source: TObject; X, Y: Integer;
  State: TDragState; var Accept: Boolean);
begin
Accept := Sender = Update_ListBox;
end;
```

how to draw selections and mouse-hover effects on ListViewDrawItem + column resizing effect?

Thanks!!!

Comment: I don't remember which Delphi version you use. It is Delphi 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to draw selections and in other ways respond to the current state of the control, you need to write additional code for this purpose, because we are owner-drawing the control. This means that we say to Windows, "hey, don't draw anything in the client area, I'll do that". Therefore, Windows draws nothing, not even selections, focus rectangles, and mouse-hover effects.

Fortunately, it is rather easy to implement this behaviour manually. Indeed, in the `OnCustomDraw` event handler, you are given a `State` parameter, which you can read. This is a set, and some of the possible elements include `odSelected`, `odHotLight`, and `odFocused`.

Building upon our previous code, adding only a few new lines, we arrive at

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1DrawItem(Sender: TCustomListView; Item: TListItem;
  Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
var
  i: Integer;
  x1, x2: integer;
  r: TRect;
  S: string;
const
  DT_ALIGN: array[TAlignment] of integer = (DT_LEFT, DT_RIGHT, DT_CENTER);
begin
  if SameText(Item.SubItems[1], 'done') then
  begin
      Sender.Canvas.Font.Color := clWhite;
      Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := clGreen;
  end
  else
    if Odd(Item.Index) then
    begin
      Sender.Canvas.Font.Color := clBlack;
      Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := $F6F6F6;
    end
    else
    begin
      Sender.Canvas.Font.Color := clBlack;
      Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite;
    end;
  if odSelected in State then                                                    // NEW!
  begin                                                                          // NEW!
    Sender.Canvas.Font.Color := clWhite;                                         // NEW!
    Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := clNavy;                                         // NEW!
  end;                                                                           // NEW!
  Sender.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
  Sender.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
  x1 := 0;
  x2 := 0;
  r := Rect;
  Sender.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
  Sender.Canvas.Draw(3, r.Top + (r.Bottom - r.Top - bm.Height) div 2, bm);
  for i := 0 to ListView1.Columns.Count - 1 do
  begin
    inc(x2, ListView1.Columns[i].Width);
    r.Left := x1;
    r.Right := x2;
    if i = 0 then
    begin
      S := Item.Caption;
      r.Left := bm.Width + 6;
    end
    else
      S := Item.SubItems[i - 1];
    DrawText(Sender.Canvas.Handle,
      S,
      length(S),
      r,
      DT_SINGLELINE or DT_ALIGN[ListView1.Columns[i].Alignment] or
        DT_VCENTER or DT_END_ELLIPSIS);
    x1 := x2;
  end;
  if odFocused in State then                                                     // NEW!
    DrawFocusRect(Sender.Canvas.Handle, Rect);                                   // NEW!
end;
```

[image: Screenshot]

Notice that the 'horse' line is selected and has keyboard focus.

Comment: Can we draw not in clNavy color but like a default selection in Windows (as usual, without OwnerDraw)? What about resizing of columns? Texts of columns are mixing. To use "update" on Resize event?

Comment: @maxfax: You have the code right above! You can edit it any way you like!

Comment: For instance, you can replace `clNavy` with `clHighlight`. Or any colour you want!

Comment: When it comes to column resizing, it works perfectly, as far as I can see.

Comment: I do not say about color, it is easy. Bur corners are rounded and there is a border in a default selection. How to copy? What do you think about a selection on Mose move?

Comment: @maxfax: That is not easy. Since we are owner-drawing, we tell Window not to draw anything. And so Windows will not. Drawing rounded rectangles with the right effects is hard. You might be somewhat successful with the visual themes API (as I have done in a lot of questions at SO), but I think it will be overkill. At first I thought you could respond to mouse-hover by testing the `odHotLight` element, but I wasn't successful.

Comment: Try to make a long string of text in columns and move the last column on a previous one - it will be mixing.

Comment: @maxfax: That has nothing to do with my code, or owner-drawing at all. Even if you let Windows draw the control, the columns will mix. If you move a column header, you will just swap the `Columns` items. You have to swap every item's subitems manually.

Comment: ok, mouse-hover and a default selection are not main things. What about a selection on mouse moving?

Comment: @maxfax: I don't understand. What is a "selection on mouse moving"?

Comment: We need to draw a selection (highlight) when mouse is over a row and deselect (not highlighted) when a mouse is not over.

Comment: @maxfax: Yes, that is the mouse-hover effect. But above you said "ok, mouse-hover and a default selection are not main things.".

Comment: Anyhow, the bug displayed in your screenshot... I cannot reproduce it (Windows 7, Aero enabled).

Comment: "At first I thought you could respond to mouse-hover by testing the odHotLight element, but I wasn't successful."

Comment: May be my code is wrong, please have a look at my code: http://sharetext.org/AST3

Comment: @maxfax: What OS are you running? Are you using visual themes?

Comment: @maxfax: Then you need to find the difference. Remove one 'feature' at a time from your 'old' project, and see when the bugs go away.

Comment: Anyhow, my 'shift' ends now, so I say "Good night!" from Sweden.

Comment: Thanks a lot! After a morning you can see the bug. Just set Autosize of a Column to True :)

Comment: Hey @AndreasRejbrand! Am I still sleepy or ``bm`` is really not declared anywhere? :)

Comment: @JacekKrawczyk: You are correct: `bm` isn't declared in the snippet above. It is simply a `TBitmap` that contains the icon shown in the list view. This is a resource you shouldn't load in each `OnDrawItem` handler, but rather once (at application startup, for instance). Exactly where you get the bitmap from and how you load it is a bit outside the topic of owner-drawing a list view, though. Probably you extract it from the app's resources, or use a `TImageList` prepared at design time, or you load it from the file system.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Oh, I see. I am just building a simple prototype of owner-drawn list, so I will not need it. Anyway, "tack så mycket" for the quick explanation.