# Delphi: bug when resizing columns of List View (on DrawItem)

Tags: delphi, listview, resize, draw

Enable **Autosize** of columns and enable OwnerDraw for a List View. Then add a code below [from HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617690/delphi-draw-selections-and-mouse-hover-effects-on-listviewdrawitem):

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1DrawItem(Sender: TCustomListView; Item: TListItem;
  Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
var
  i: Integer;
  x1, x2: integer;
  r: TRect;
  S: string;
const
  DT_ALIGN: array[TAlignment] of integer = (DT_LEFT, DT_RIGHT, DT_CENTER);
begin
  if SameText(Item.SubItems[1], 'done') then
  begin
      Sender.Canvas.Font.Color := clWhite;
      Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := clGreen;
  end
  else
    if Odd(Item.Index) then
    begin
      Sender.Canvas.Font.Color := clBlack;
      Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := $F6F6F6;
    end
    else
    begin
      Sender.Canvas.Font.Color := clBlack;
      Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite;
    end;
  if odSelected in State then                                                    // NEW!
  begin                                                                          // NEW!
    Sender.Canvas.Font.Color := clWhite;                                         // NEW!
    Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := clNavy;                                         // NEW!
  end;                                                                           // NEW!
  Sender.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
  Sender.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
  x1 := 0;
  x2 := 0;
  r := Rect;
  Sender.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
  Sender.Canvas.Draw(3, r.Top + (r.Bottom - r.Top - bm.Height) div 2, bm);
  for i := 0 to ListView1.Columns.Count - 1 do
  begin
    inc(x2, ListView1.Columns[i].Width);
    r.Left := x1;
    r.Right := x2;
    if i = 0 then
    begin
      S := Item.Caption;
      r.Left := bm.Width + 6;
    end
    else
      S := Item.SubItems[i - 1];
    DrawText(Sender.Canvas.Handle,
      S,
      length(S),
      r,
      DT_SINGLELINE or DT_ALIGN[ListView1.Columns[i].Alignment] or
        DT_VCENTER or DT_END_ELLIPSIS);
    x1 := x2;
  end;
  if odFocused in State then                                                     // NEW!
    DrawFocusRect(Sender.Canvas.Handle, Rect);                                   // NEW!
end;
```

Actively resize the **penultimate** column if it has autosize. It bill be bugs:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

How to prevent these bugs?­­­­­­­­

Thanks!

Comment: What is the question? "It will be bugs" isn't specific enough.

Comment: I do not know how to describe it exactly. They are on the picture. See?

Comment: I can see the picture. I don't know what's wrong though.

Comment: if autosize is disabled then all will be ok

Comment: @David: I don't think there is anything wrong with my (as it happens...) code at all, from a 'theoretical' point of view. Instead, I think that custom drawing is poorly supported by the operating system, at least since the advent of visual themes. I guess you are also familiar with the inevitable 'black hotlight' bug that appears as soon as one performs any kind of custom drawing in a `TListView`.

Comment: @Andreas I'd expect that one should be using the theme API for custom drawing. But it is a nasty business to get into. A classic example is the total abortion that is VistaDraw from Menus.pas. I've spent the past 6 months on and off fixing bugs  in there until yesterday I finally produced a beautiful solution and arranged for it not to run and for the system to draw the menus in my app. Documentation for the theme API is diabolically bad.

Comment: Is not there any normal way to paint rows without gaps in Delphi? Without bugs? Many programs use this effect, and it turned out impossible to do...

Comment: I can duplicate the problem without themes, I guess it's only related with the 'AutoSize' feature of TListColumns, there's no problem with the OS.

Comment: @Sertac: It seems you were right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bug is in the `TListColumn.GetWidth`in 'comctrls.pas'. The VCL is retrieving a wrong column width while resizing columns when 'AutoSize' on the columns is set, hence you're drawing item text all over the columns.

I looked at the VCL code for a few minutes and couldn't figure out what's wrong, but setting the value in a getter is suspicious enough.

Anyway, for a workaround, instead of

```
inc(x2, ListView1.Columns[i].Width);
```

use this:

```
inc(x2, ListView_GetColumnWidth(ListView1.Handle, ListView1.Columns[i].Index));
```

Comment: ListView_GetColumnWidth is in ComCtrls. But in my program it is "undeclared identifier"

Comment: @maxfax - Sorry, include 'commctrl' in your uses clause.

Comment: @maxfax: Add `CommCtrl` to the `uses` list.

Comment: Hey guys, what can I say... talents!