# Delphi: Color Item in ListView

Tags: delphi, listview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ListView in vsReport mode colouring of Items and rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294985/listview-in-vsreport-mode-colouring-of-items-and-rows)

I have a problem: items in ListView are added to a separate thread, some of these elements must be in color, but they are colored only when the pointer to bring to item. How to solve this problem?

Color element of doing so (OnAdvancedCustomDrawItem):

```
procedure TFGlavnaya.LVThreadsListAdvancedCustomDrawItem(
  Sender: TCustomListView; Item: TListItem; State: TCustomDrawState;
  Stage: TCustomDrawStage; var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
begin
  try
    if Item.SubItems[0] = '' then
      begin
        Sender.Canvas.Font.Color := clBlue;
        Sender.Canvas.Font.Style := Sender.Canvas.Font.Style + [fsBold];
      end;
  except
    Exit;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I have another problem. Generally,it was necessary to forcibly redraw the ListView. I think, solved that problem with BeginUpdate and EndUpdate.

Comment: If you want to just redraw some list view items, use the [`UpdateItems`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomListView.UpdateItems) method. There you can specify the range of the updated (redrawn) items.

Comment: What do you mean by "added to a separate thread". I hope you aren't doing UI outside the GUI thread.