# How can I restore the Highlight function in an owner-drawn ListView

Tags: delphi, ownerdrawn, tlistview

I wrote some code to make the first row white, second grey, third white, and so on. To do that, I had to use `OwnerDraw=true`, but now the ListView doesn't respond as it used to when you hover over a row. How do I add that back?

This is what I have now:

```pascal
procedure TAchievementTracker.lvAchievementsDrawItem(Sender: TSMView;
  Item: TSMListItem; Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
var
  i: Integer;
  x1, x2: integer;
  r: TRect;
  S: string;
const
  DT_ALIGN: array[TAlignment] of integer = (DT_LEFT, DT_RIGHT, DT_CENTER);
begin
  if Odd(Item.Index) then
  begin
    Sender.Canvas.Font.Color := clBlack;
    Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := $F6F6F6;
  end
  else
  begin
    Sender.Canvas.Font.Color := clBlack;
    Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite;
  end;
  Sender.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
  Sender.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
  x1 := 0;
  x2 := 0;
  r := Rect;
  Sender.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
  for i := 0 to lvAchievements.Columns.Count - 1 do
  begin
    inc(x2, lvAchievements.Columns[i].Width);
    r.Left := x1;
    r.Right := x2;
    if i = 0 then
      S := Item.Caption
    else
      S := '   ' + Item.SubItems[i-1];
    DrawText(Sender.Canvas.Handle,
      S,
      length(S),
      r,
      DT_SINGLELINE or DT_ALIGN[lvAchievements.Columns[i].Alignment] or
        DT_VCENTER or DT_END_ELLIPSIS);
    x1 := x2;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Please, confirm which event you use. Actually better show the procedure you have now.

Comment: Check for `odFocused in State`. If true use the highlight colors. Or if you want to show that the mouse is hovering over an item, check for `odHotLight in State`.

Comment: William: When you copied this code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6295592/282848), you should have made an attempt to fully understand it. In this case, the first thing on your mind should have been to read the documentation for the [`OnDrawItem`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomListView.OnDrawItem) event. Then you should have followed the link to the [`TLVDrawItemEvent`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TLVDrawItemEvent) page which describes the `State` param: "indicates [...] whether it is selected, grayed, or focused."

Comment: But now that I investigate this further, I realise that the hot effect, specifically, is much harder to achieve.

Comment: @Tom: You probably mean `odSelected`, not `odFocused`.

Comment: Yes @Andreas, I was in a hurry and made a mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a simpler way to colour the lines of a list view control than to use full owner drawing. You can use the `OnCustomDrawItem` event even if `OwnerDraw` is `False`:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.ListView1CustomDrawItem(Sender: TCustomListView;
  Item: TListItem; State: TCustomDrawState; var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
const
  BgColors: array[Boolean] of TColor = (clWhite, clSilver);
  FgColors: array[Boolean] of TColor = (clBlack, clBlack);
begin
  Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := BgColors[Odd(Item.Index)];
  Sender.Canvas.Font.Color := FgColors[Odd(Item.Index)];
end;
```

This actually preserves the themed hover and selected effects:

[image: Screen recording of the list view in action.]

The problem is that the standard themed effects typically look bad together with the custom colours.

So perhaps it is better to fully custom-draw it (`OwnerDraw = True`):

```pascal
procedure TForm1.ListView1DrawItem(Sender: TCustomListView; Item: TListItem;
  Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
const
  BgColors: array[Boolean] of TColor = (clWhite, clSilver);
  FgColors: array[Boolean] of TColor = (clBlack, clBlack);
  Alignments: array[TAlignment] of TTextFormats = (tfLeft, tfRight, tfCenter);
var
  LV: TListView;
  i, x1, x2: Integer;
  R: TRect;
  S: string;
begin

  LV := Sender as TListView;

  if [odSelected, odHotLight] * State <> [] then
  begin
    LV.Canvas.Brush.Color := clNavy;
    LV.Canvas.Font.Color := clWhite;
  end
  else
  begin
    LV.Canvas.Brush.Color := BgColors[Odd(Item.Index)];
    LV.Canvas.Font.Color := FgColors[Odd(Item.Index)];
  end;

  LV.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
  LV.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);

  x1 := 0;
  x2 := 0;
  R := Rect;
  LV.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;

  for i := 0 to LV.Columns.Count - 1 do
  begin
    Inc(x2, LV.Columns[i].Width);
    R.Left := x1;
    R.Right := x2;
    if i = 0 then
      S := Item.Caption
    else
      S := Item.SubItems[i - 1];
    S := #32 + S;
    LV.Canvas.TextRect(R, S, [tfSingleLine,
      Alignments[LV.Columns[i].Alignment], tfVerticalCenter, tfEndEllipsis]);
    x1 := x2;
  end;

  if odFocused in State then
  begin
    LV.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
    LV.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlack;
    LV.Canvas.Font.Color := clWhite;
    Rect.Inflate(-1, -1);
    DrawFocusRect(LV.Canvas.Handle, Rect);
  end;

end;
```

[image: Screen recording of the new code in action.]

Unfortunately, as you can see, this introduces new problems, such as an alignment issue, which I "solved" in a very sloppy way in this snippet. Also, it seems like this approach doesn't allow you to produce a hover ("hot") effect. The snippet above supports highlight and focus, but not hover.

## OK, let's do it!

If you really, really, want the hot effect, there's always a way:

Set the list view control's `Tag` to `-1`, let

```pascal
procedure TForm1.ListView1DrawItem(Sender: TCustomListView; Item: TListItem;
  Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
const
  BgColors: array[Boolean] of TColor = (clWhite, clSilver);
  FgColors: array[Boolean] of TColor = (clBlack, clBlack);
  Alignments: array[TAlignment] of TTextFormats = (tfLeft, tfRight, tfCenter);
var
  LV: TListView;
  i, x1, x2: Integer;
  R: TRect;
  S: string;
begin

  LV := Sender as TListView;

  if ListView1.Tag = Item.Index then                 //
  begin                                              //
    LV.Canvas.Brush.Color := clSkyBlue;              //   NEW
    LV.Canvas.Font.Color := clBlack;                 //
  end                                                //
  else if odSelected in State then
  begin
    LV.Canvas.Brush.Color := clNavy;
    LV.Canvas.Font.Color := clWhite;
  end
  else
  begin
    LV.Canvas.Brush.Color := BgColors[Odd(Item.Index)];
    LV.Canvas.Font.Color := FgColors[Odd(Item.Index)];
  end;

  LV.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
  LV.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);

  x1 := 0;
  x2 := 0;
  R := Rect;
  LV.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;

  for i := 0 to LV.Columns.Count - 1 do
  begin
    Inc(x2, LV.Columns[i].Width);
    R.Left := x1;
    R.Right := x2;
    if i = 0 then
      S := Item.Caption
    else
      S := Item.SubItems[i - 1];
    S := #32 + S;
    LV.Canvas.TextRect(R, S, [tfSingleLine,
      Alignments[LV.Columns[i].Alignment], tfVerticalCenter, tfEndEllipsis]);
    x1 := x2;
  end;

  if (odFocused in State) and not (odNoFocusRect in State) then
  begin
    LV.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
    LV.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlack;
    LV.Canvas.Font.Color := clWhite;
    Rect.Inflate(-1, -1);
    DrawFocusRect(LV.Canvas.Handle, Rect);
  end;

end;
```

and add the following `OnMouseMove` handler:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.ListView1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
var
  LI: TListItem;
  Idx: Integer;
begin
  LI := ListView1.GetItemAt(X, Y);
  if Assigned(LI) then
    Idx := LI.Index
  else
    Idx := -1;
  if Idx <> ListView1.Tag then
  begin
    ListView1.Tag := Idx;
    ListView1.Invalidate; // maybe overkill
  end;
end;
```

and the following `OnMouseLeave` handler:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.ListView1MouseLeave(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if ListView1.Tag <> -1 then
  begin
    ListView1.Tag := -1;
    ListView1.Invalidate;
  end;
end;
```

[image: Screen recording of the last example.]

Comment: I tried to move the code to `CustomDrawItem`, setting `OwnerDraw` to `False`, and using `Item.DisplayRect(drBounds)` to compensate for the missing `Rect` parameter, and this makes it possible to respond to the hot state. However, the result is exceedingly buggy (Delphi 10.3, Win7 64-bit, Aero, high DPI)! Can someone confirm this?

Comment: I think this highlights a "principle" or "law": It is easy to use a system (like a GUI control) the way it is supposed to be used, without any modifications, and it is also easy to write a system from scratch yourself (a custom control), so you get full control over all the details. However, customising an existing system to suit your own, non-standard, needs, is difficult.

Comment: "*it seems like this approach doesn't allow you to produce a hover ("hot") effect*" - it is fairly easy to implement manually if `odHotLight` is not working. Use the `OnMouseMove` event to keep track of which item is under the mouse at all times via [`TListView.GetItemAt()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomListView.GetItemAt) (or use [`LVM_HITTEST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lvm-hittest) directly), and then have the drawing code compare that to the item being drawn when deciding which colors to use.

Comment: Or, look at [`LVM_GETHOTITEM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lvm-gethotitem) instead.

Comment: Of course, but then the complexity increases even more, and you might ask yourself if it really is worth it.

Comment: Couldn't resist.